# How to let Python interact with the stdout/stdin of GDB console?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, gdb-python, semihosting

I am trying to make some automation testing with an embedded application running in an ARM Microcontroller. For the I/O exchange I have setup the Semihosting using arm-none-eabi-gdb as GDB client:

> arm-none-eabi-gdb my_binary.axf -ex "target localhost::3333" -ex"load" -ex "continue"

After launching the GDB session I am able to use printf(), scanf() to interact with the user through the GDB console.

I am now **desperately trying** to make Python read and write to/from the gdb console in order to substitute the user, but the results so far have been poor.

This is the best solution I tried without any success:

- Create a new gdb console into a separate pseudo terminal with the following GDB command:

> **(gdb)** new-ui console /dev/ptyp0

and let Python open/read/write the device /dev/ttyp0. The connections seems to be properly established but I am not able to neither read nor write any data from the GDB console.

(ref: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Interpreters.html)

Which is the best way to solve this problem?

I am totally running out of solutions here and it would be great to know is someone has already tried to do the same thing.

Comment: Use `pexpect` to write a script that controls an interactive application.

Comment: @Barmar seems to be a good idea but I have to exchange binary strings to send commands and receive responses.